# Efficient JSON search in Java

Tags: java, json

Good Day!
In Java, is there any way to search a large JSON by keys efficiently.

My Sample JSON:

```
{
    "my_data": [
        {
            "id": "12",
            "message": "z1",
            "text": "hai"
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "message": "z2",
            "text": "get"
        },
        {
            "id": "14",
            "message": "z3",
            "text": "up"
        }
    ]
}
```

The 'my_data' JsonArray is very lengthy. As it is very large, it takes more time to search a particular word in it as:

```
my_data.get(index).getString("text").contains(SEARCH_STRING)
```

Is there any pre-defined libraries or standard technique to search efficiently?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is pure text data, you can process them with standard text search tools like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), and find your entry based on that.

Comment: Thank you. Let me look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

Fast json parser is [Jackson Java JSON-processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
, but it have to read sequentially whole String to find your value. So if you need something faster you probably must save your data in another format than JSON, you will need some sort of index. (But it depends on what you want to do and how fast it must be ...)

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply. So on considering the above JSON, can I use Jackson  processor to search for a particular word say "hai" in the key "text"?